# Delete all files starting with a question mark

Tags: shell, wildcards, quoting

I have a folder in which I have around 4k files. Some of these files start with a a `?` or `!` character. I need to delete them but can't find an expression that would do so:

`rm -f ./?*`

just deletes everything. I can possibly use `grep` on ls and pipe it through `xargs` and move files to another folder but I was hoping there was a proper way of doing this. Need help on both the `?` and `!` files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No need for any fancy stuff. Simply escape the `?` so that it's not considered part of the glob:

```
rm -f ./\?*
```

This works for `!` too:

```
rm -f ./\!*
```

Or in one fell swoop:

```
rm -f ./{\?,\!}*
```

**Update**

Just noticed that you were suggesting to `grep` the output of `ls`. I wanted to bring your attention to the fact that [you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @recluze Not stupid; it's far from obvious how to do it if you don't know about wildcard escaping.

Comment: @recluze Still feel stupid after 5 votes on your question? :) By the way, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks and thanks :) ... Was aware of the problems in ls output but my files had a particular pattern that I could count on. Nevertheless, good to know :)

Answer (score 24):

In my case, the characters were not really question marks, but unicode characters that apparently could not be displayed in my console.

Using `rm -i *` worked for me. If you don't want to do this, you can also delete by inode, as described at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-remove-files-with-inode-number.html.

To find the inode, use:

```
ls -il
```

Then do:

```
find . -inum [inode-number] -exec rm -i {} \;
```